# Ars longa, vita brevis.

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, math-history

There's little use studying mathematics without actually doing mathematics. There is a plethora of exercises in any textbook worth its salt. I suppose those with some business in looking up something might hone in on what exercises to do. I have research to do as a PhD student and I *still* don't.

> Should one do a kind of mathematical *calisthenics*, training daily with the mundane like doing scales for a musician or should one sink one's teeth into some impossible problem then let its foreplay and teasing guide the way?

*NB:* To avoid this becoming primarily opinion-based, let's concentrate on the work habits of the greats, through the mediocre, to the average Joe.

Comment: Solving exercises in books will not make you better & better. Many of them use the same ideas, and doing them all is redundant, and *all* of them use ideas spoon fed to you by the books. Do not waste time on solving what you already know how to solve, skip it. There is only so far that exercises can take you, acquiring basic skills and intuition. After a while, start finding problems that interest you, but no method you know applies, research them, solve subproblems that come up, and let that guide what you read and what exercises you solve. Wean yourself off the textbooks and take control.

Comment: @Conifold It depends on the book. Classical textbooks in analysis and complex analysis are well-known for their rewarding and challenging collections of exercises. The exercises in "The axiom of choice" book by Jech include open problems. And so on.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\text{Caeli, Lesbia nostra, Lesbia illa}\cr  
\text{illa Lesbia, quam Catullus unam}\cr
\text{plus quam se atque suos amavit omnes,}\cr
\text{nunc in quadriviis et angiportis}\cr
\text{glubit magnanimi Remi nepotes.}\end{array}$$

Comment: I don't know if this will be of much help, but this transition is sort of "just happening" to me.  I learned LA, Calc, and MV Calc in a very "visual first" manner, starting each by studying 3Blue1Brown videos.  Then I started studying ODEs from a book, and when I reached exact/inexact equations, I stumbled across a hierarchical explosion of conceptual questions, which has now led me down the path of attempting to find general integrating factors analytically.  I don't expect to be successful, but I've learned a number of interesting things along the way.